# Web APi Casting parameter to its original type on the OnActionExecuting method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In web Api I'm writing a custom attribute.In the OnActionExecuting method I want to get the parameter passed to the Action method and cast it to its original type.
I'm getting the parameter at like that

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ActionParameters = actionContext.ActionArguments;
        object param = ActionParameters.First().Value;


        var actionInfo = actionContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var parameter = actionInfo.GetParameters().First();
        string p = parameter.ParameterType.FullName;
        Type t = Type.GetType(p + "," + "Models"); //Type of the parameter
    }
```

There is supposed to be only one parameter.Now I dont know the exact type of parameter.I just know that parameter will have couple of properties.How can I cast the parameter to its original type.

Answer (score 0):

ActionArguments is a Dictionary generic dixtionaryof string and object.It stores values as object so you need to cast it to the type you are expecting.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    ActionParameters = actionContext.ActionArguments;
    if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("Key1"))
    {
      var val = actionContext.ActionArguments["Key1"] as string;
    }        
}
```